# How to set the image resolution for animations?

Tags: animation, matplotlib

how can I set the resolution of an animation saved as mp4 movie with "matplotlib.animation" module?

On the web I only found examples using "animation.FuncAnimation". For example the nice tutorial from http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/ used:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

From the matplotlib.animation module reference I found the "animation.Animation.save" method providing a "dpi"-argument, but I don't know how to apply this function properly

```
matplotlib.animation.Animation.save(filename, writer=None, fps=None, dpi=None, codec=None, bitrate=None, extra_args=None, metadata=None, extra_anim=None)
```

A small example code may be helpful.

Many thanks.

Johannes

PS: By the way, how can you insert Python-code with sytax-highlighting?

Comment: The highlighting is auto-magical.  Also note that the animation module is relatively, so you have to check that your version of `matplotlib` matches the version of examples you find.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 23):

You can control the resolution in a round-about way.  The resolution, figure size, and dpi are not all independent, if you know two of them, then the third is fixed.

You can set the `dpi` in the save argument, and before you save it, set the size of the figure with

```
fig.set_size_inches(w_in_inches, h_in_inches, True).
```

Your resolution is then `dpi * w_in_inches X dpi * h_in_inches`.

```
dpi = 100
writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg'](fps=30)
ani.save('test.mp4',writer=writer,dpi=dpi)
```

You may need do upgrade to a newer version of mpl (debian is great because it is so conservative and awful because it is so conservative) from source.

Comment: Hmm ok, but the same TypeError as with the "bitrate"-argument:
`anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, frames=len(t), blit=True) 

animation.Animation.save(anim,'toll.mp4', fps=20, dpi=800, codec='mp4')`  I get the error "save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dpi'"

Comment: Ok many thanks, now it is working, the "figure.set_dpi()" method has no effect, but calling `fig.set_size_inches(h_in_inches, w_in_inches)` results in an image resolution of "h_in_inches  xw_in_inches".

Comment: @mr_endres what version of MPL are you using?

Comment: Newest version from Debian Sid: 1.1.1~rc2-1

Comment: The above answer may have worked 10 years ago, but how do we set the resolution now, with matplotlib version 3.8.2? The dpi parameter of ani.save() method does not work, i.e. it produces different results on identical installations of Python 3.12.0 on different computers, which is obviously wrong. So, how does one set the resolution consistently and explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

`bitrate` is the parameter used to specify the quality of a movie. The higher the value you set it to, the higher the quality of the movie will be.

Comment: But if I ran the above example with

`anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, frames=len(t), blit=True)
animation.Animation.save(anim,'toll.mp4', fps=20, bitrate=20, codec='mp4')`
I got the error "save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bitrate'".

Comment: I think `bitrate` (and maybe `dpi`) were added circa MPL 1.2.

Comment: Works for me now with mpl 1.3. Also, amazing answer, this was the reason my movies where not displaying properly and taking forever to save as well.